# Google Maps & Flex: How to Use Standard Map Marker Instead of Custom Marker?

Tags: google-maps, apache-flex, google-maps-markers

I'm using Google Maps with Flex 3. I'm using custom markers (custom icons) to mark places on the map. It works fine. The problem is that in some cases, I don't need a custom icon, I need the standard marker.

For example, how would I set condition C's icon to the standard marker:

```
public function iconSetter():void {
    if (condition A blah blah){myIcon=star; myPointsBuilder(); return;}
    if (condition B blah blah){myIcon=circle; myPointsBuilder(); return;}
    if (condition C blah blah){myIcon=STANDARD MARKER; myPointsBuilder(); return;}
    }
```

In the myPointsBuilder function I create the markers like so:

```
for  (i=0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        myMarker = new Marker(new LatLng(myData[i].latitude, myData[i].longitude), new MarkerOptions({
        icon: new myIcon, iconOffset: new Point(2,2), iconAlignment:1,  hasShadow:true
        }));
        markerBoss.addMarker(myMarker, 15, 15); 
        }
        markerBoss.refresh();
```

I don't know how to revert to the default marker where I wrote "STANDARD MARKER". Any suggestions?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: if you just want the standard icon, why are you even setting the icon in the marker options?

Comment: Hi JAX, Thank you for the message. In cases A&B I need custom markers. In case C, I need the default marker. If you have a suggestion, I'd love to hear it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for  (i=0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
   myMarker = new Marker(new LatLng(myData[i].latitude, myData[i].longitude));
   switch(condition)
   {
      case A:
      case B:
         myMarket.setOptions(new MarkerOptions({icon: new myIcon, iconOffset: new Point(2,2), iconAlignment:1,  hasShadow:true}));
         break;
      case C: // default, do nothing
         break;
   }
   markerBoss.addMarker(myMarker, 15, 15); 
}
markerBoss.refresh();
```

This is untested, but you get the idea